A risk lover will never buy insurance or pay premium?
An individual faces an uncertain prospect, where wealth could be Rs. 10 Lakh with
probability 0.75 and Rs. 7 Lakh with probability 0.25.
Let the utility function be U (w) = w^3. Then the individual will buy full insurance by
paying a premium of Rs. Lakh __________________
Clearly the person is a risk lover as we can derive from the utility function.From my knowledge what I think is that the person won't buy insurance and hence insurance premium will be 0.
Rectify me if I'm wrong.

While your intuition is certainly in the right direction, I think the intent of the question is for you to derive from the given utility function and prospect the precise value of the premium.

Using the formula to calculate insurance premium the precise value is coming -.2 approx.

That looks about right. You'll just have to interpret what it means for someone who is willing to pay a negative amount to fully insure against risk.
